# Forms in a Microsoft Access .MDA wont open when the .MDA File is Checked out from Tortoise SVN

Tags: ms-access, svn, tortoisesvn

I have the following Problem:

I recently started using TortoiseSVN in order to Commit and Checkout .MDA Files, and while testing everything out I noticed that .MDA Files that have been Checked out of TortoiseSVN have a problem with Forms. They simply dont Open in Access when double clicked, no Error Message, no Window, simply nothing happens. In order to Fix this, I currently simply rename a control in the Form and Name it back to the Original Name. This usually fixes the Problem but is a time consuming process in .MDA Files with many Forms.

Is there a known Fix for this Problem or does someone have an Idea why this Problem occurs?

Comment: Why mda files and not mdb? Does that make a difference?

Comment: Due to Software Limitations I am bound to use .MDA files.

Comment: Try adding the `svn:mime-type` property to your file set to the value "application/binary" before committing. Then try checking the file out -- all should be normal. See [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html) for background.